# Checking Internet Connection using SmartGWT or GWT?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

How can we check if there is Internet connectivity in the application or not in SmartGWT or GWT? I have to determine that whether there is internet connection or not and based on that change the icon for Internet connectivity to either green or red so is there a way to do it in SmartGWT or GWT?

Comment: connectivity to your web server? Or if the application is running on a corporate network, connectivity to outside the network?

Comment: the application needs to monitor continuously that whether the internet access is available or not and based on that modify the icon to green or red. In simple words if I am connected to Wi-Fi the icon should be green and if disconnected the icon should be red. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a native method in which you create a new image object (new Image()) and attach handler to it's onload and onerror properties. You can point the image's src property to some URL that you feel indicates being online. Then from your onload and onerror methods you can call methods in your GWT component to update your connectivity indicator. You need to set img.src after you set img.onload and img.onerror.

For example:

```
native void checkConnectivity(Example obj) /*-{
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {           
      obj.@com.example.client.Example::online()();
    }
    img.onerror = function() {                    
      obj.@com.example.client.Example::offline()();
    }
    img.src = "http://exampleapp.com/test.gif";
}-*/;
```

Comment: Will this continuously monitor the internet connectivity?

Comment: You'll have to use a GWT timer to execute the method periodically.

Comment: There seems to a problem as this does not check internet connectivity.

Comment: well it depending on what URL you provided in img.src. Does it point to a resource on the LAN or is it on the WWW? Try accessing the resource directly in the browser. Perhaps there are filters preventing direct access.

Comment: In the methods of the GWT component I have added code to update the image icon and regarding the img.src I was trying to point it to some image on WWW. So will there be any kind of cross domain connectivity concern as there is a problem with that. Kindly suggest what should be the approach. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I pointed my img.src to a resource on our public website (different domain from where the app was hosted), otherwise it's much more likely that your app's connectivity feature will suddenly stop working. Same-origin policy permits images to come from other domains.

Comment: I don't get it. U mean I can point my img.src to a resource which is on some other domain and still it will work as SOP permits images to come from other domain. Correct me if I am wrong as I am trying that in JSFiddle and I am running into an error.

Comment: I need last thing from your side. I am unable figure out how to call this function periodically plus it is giving compilation error.

Comment: Yes, you can point to a domain other than where the app is hosted. I can't help with you compilation error since I don't know what it is. For calling things periodically, use the Timer class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the navigator.onLine will help you:

http://html5demos.com/offline

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/offline

You may need to wrap the calls into JSNI and also implement an eventlistener.

```
public native Boolean isOnline()/*-{
    return window.onLine;
}-*/;
```

Comment: I want to check whether there is internet access or not and i think this checks whether the browser is Online or Offline mode. Thanks!

Comment: Nope, this also holds true, for internet connectivity (at least for chrome)

Comment: Well i need this to be compatible with all the browsers btw thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Please replace `Boolean` with `boolean` i.e. `public native boolean isOnline()/*-{`

Answer (score 0):

`Udeleng`'s solution is the closest i have come to a cross-browser approach. I have been testing it on FF 18 but i believe it will work in any browser.

However, note that the browser pre-loads the image when you call `new Image()`, caching it such that subsequent calls to the same URL don't make an HTTP call. This kills the effect we want to achieve i.e. transition from `offline` to `online` status works but as soon as the browser gets any connection, the image is cached, and end of story, even if you unplug your ethernet cable.

**SOLUTION**
Add a state parameter to the URL and give it a random number, the idea is to trick the browser into thinking its a new image such that the image is fetched from the server each time, rather than the cache.

Of course you need to add the timer. Here is my code:

```js
import com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer;
import com.smartgwt.client.util.SC;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Img;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.DrawEvent;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.DrawHandler;
public class WebConnChecker extends Img {
 private static final String ONLINE="online_stat.jpg";
 private static final String OFFLINE="offline_stat.jpg";
 private static final int INTERVAL=10000;
 private Timer timer;

 public WebConnChecker(){
  setSize(16);
  timer=new Timer() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    checkConnectivity(WebConnChecker.this);
   }
  };
  addDrawHandler(new DrawHandler() {
   
   @Override
   public void onDraw(DrawEvent event) {
    timer.scheduleRepeating(INTERVAL);

   }
  });  
 }
 private void online(){
  log("online detected");
  this.setSrc(ONLINE);
 }
 private void offline(){
  log("offline detected");
  this.setSrc(OFFLINE);
 }

 private native void checkConnectivity(WebConnChecker checker) /*-{
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() { 
     window.alert("online");          
      checker.@com.telligent.smap.student.client.util.WebConnChecker::online()();
    }
    img.onerror = function() {  
        window.alert("offline");                
      checker.@com.telligent.smap.student.client.util.WebConnChecker::offline()();
    }
    img.src = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=41f6e13ade69&state="+Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}-*/;
}
```

**Hope it works for you**